# How to pass variables to OpenModalDialogCommand

Tags: 8, forms

Drupal 8.
Clicking the upload button on Form1 should open UploadForm in a modal dialog.

```
/**
 * Callback to display a modal.
 */
public function ajaxSubmit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $op = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#return_value'];
  switch ($op) {
    case 'upload':
      $modal = new OpenModalDialogCommand(
        t('Upload file(s)'), 
          render(\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('UploadForm', 
            $this->nid, $this->foo, $this->bar))));
      break;

    // ... other cases.
  }

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->setAttachments($form['#attached']);
  $response->addCommand($modal);
  return $response;
}
```

I'm not able to pass the variables to UploadForm. `$this->` properties don't appear in UploadForm.

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('UploadForm', $this->nid, $this->foo, $this->bar));
```

The form also fails if I replace the variables by local variables

```
$nid, $foo, $bar
```

But it works when I replace them by

```
'28', 'foo', 'bar'
```

The non-ajax version of the form uses a redirect to a form route (`my_module.uploadform`) and works OK.
Is there a way to pass the parameters to UploadForm?

Comment: Does your class define and assign values to `$this->nid`, `$this->foo`, and `$this->bar`? If it doesn't, the code doesn't work. The same is true for `$nid`, `$foo`, and `$bar` since the method you are showing doesn't have any of those local variables. If it works when you use constant values, then the problem is merely using not defined properties/variables.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
Thanks @kiamlaluno.
I was convinced the variables were OK. But after your comment and a fresh look I saw what I was missing:
`$this->nid, $this->foo, $this->bar` are optional parameters for the UploadForm formbuilder. I was passing only `nid` and `bar`, but missing `foo`, which messed-up things.
So, instead of:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('UploadForm', $this->nid, $this->bar) //don't need foo
```

I needed to call:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('UploadForm', $this->nid, null, $this->bar)
```

A bit obvious, I'm afraid...

Comment: Hey, if this is the right answer to you question, please mark it. So others will recognize easily that this problem got solved sufficiently. It's totally fine to accept your own answer.